# Load all the files from a directory in clojure

Tags: clojure

How can I load every clojure file from a directory?

The following code doesn't work but speak of itself ("folder" is in my src/project directory)

```
(load "folder/*")
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? and do you expect to do that without having conflicts in the namespaces and dependencies?

Comment: I've got some namespaces that getting too big for one file so i've splitted it into several files that i'm loading into my main ns file with the load function, i could be handy to be able to import all of them in one function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following function does what you are looking for, given the scenario you described it doesn't seem necessary to check dependencies so the function doesn't do anything but use `load-file` with all the files in the provided path.

```
(defn load-files [path]
  (let [file  (java.io.File. path)
        files (.listFiles file)]
  (doseq [x files]
    (when (.isFile x)
      (load-file (.getCanonicalPath x))))))

(load-files ".")
```

The docs for [`listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) say that there's no guarantee on the order the files are returned, so a possible improvement would be to provide a key-function (a function that returns the key on which the sort is done) to do the sorting.

```
(defn load-files [path f]
  (let [file  (java.io.File. path)
        files (sort-by f (.listFiles file))]
  (doseq [x files]
    (when (.isFile x)
      (load-file (.getCanonicalPath x))))))

(load-files "." #(.getName %))
```

If you want to load all files in the directory tree then you could use `file-seq` as suggested by [@edbond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1362000/edbond).

```
(defn load-files [path f]
  (let [files (->> path java.io.File. file-seq (sort-by f))]
  (doseq [x files]
    (when (.isFile x)
      (load-file (.getCanonicalPath x))))))

(load-files "." #(.getName %))
```

Comment: file-seq may be used here

Comment: @edbond `file-seq` could be used but that would list files in the sub-directories in `path` as well, but then again maybe that's what the OP wants. I'll add a third implementation with `file-seq`.

Comment: This will not work in clojurescript outside the REPL. This does not appear to be a clojurescript question and the tag is misleading. Just FYI to someone who can edit tags.